# Grab word out of sentence

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I've seen "split string" for this sort of thing, but I need something specific. I need the program to identify if the user put in a specific word into a sentence. I'm using it to program a very, VERY shoddy, basic AI program.

If the user inputs something like, "What is your name?" it will recognize that the user said "name" and go to a random name generator.

What is the code for grabbing a specific word (ignoring case) from a sentence so I can use it later (like in an if-else or something)?

Comment: Can you use string.contains()?

Answer (score 3):

it is possible to use Regex that support word boundary in Java

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\bname\\b");
Matcher m = patt.matcher(" v padaname bla");    
System.out.println(m.find());
m = patt.matcher(" your name?");    
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do this:

```
if(string.toLowerCase().contains(" name")){
//Random Name generator
}
```

EDIT:
Upon further revision, I believe regex to be the answer, the regex `"\bname\b"` would work but you would need to escape it for java so `"\\bname\\b"` ... @JosefN's answer is the one you want..

Comment: I knew there was something like contain, I just couldn't remember it. Thanks, man! (@Shaun Wild)

Comment: That would also trigger on "ornament", "tournament", and "enamel".

Comment: @DonReba - exactly...

Comment: Oops, edited :P.. I didn't think this through before posting an answer. Wow. Let me go and think about this. Hold on.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use contains() method blindly ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello my name is someGuy";
        System.out.println(str.contains("name"));
        String strNew = "hello my namespace is Test";
        System.out.println(strNew.contains("name"));
    } 

OP : true
     true
```

Use "JosefN"'s answer...

Comment: "My name, which is unique...." and this fails. The regex is optimal here.

Comment: @MarioStoilov - I totally agree... Thats why I said.. if you are sure that all words are seperated by single space.. and "name" can never come in any other context, then use " name " as a safety